# "On the periphery" or "in the periphery"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Are both of these valid?

> **on** the periphery
>
> **in** the periphery

What would be the appropriate usage? Would it be sufficient to use *peripheral* as a replacement?

Comment: It depends on the context. If "the periphery" is quite a large expanse of land surrounding a city, for example, things could validly be *"in"* it. If it's the periphery of a circle you've just drawn in your geometry exercise book, things can only be *"on"* it. You can also speak of things *"at the periphery"*. Technically speaking, a periphery is a boundary line with no thickness, but in practice we often ignore that. Exact context could also dictate whether *"peripheral"* is acceptable/better as a replacement.

Answer (score 5):

Macmillan Dictionary defines *[periphery](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/periphery)* as:

> **periphery**, *noun* : the outer part of an area, very far from the center

It includes this phrase as an example usage:

> **on the periphery of something**: *Each republic occupied a territory on the periphery of the Soviet Union.*

You can also say **at** the periphery (*the party moved so far to the right that what had been at the periphery was now the center*) or **along** the periphery (*an invisible electric fence runs along the periphery of my property*).

You can say **in** the periphery if you are referring to the very edges of something (*he drove until he caught the outline of a shed in the periphery of the truck's headlights*). It's common to see economics or history textbooks (like [this one](http://bit.ly/xeJIF3)) discussing countries *in the core*, or center, and countries **in the periphery**.

If something is on, in, or at the periphery, then you can say it is [*peripheral*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/peripheral) (*peripheral republics were far from Moscow, geographically, culturally, and linguistically*).